# to display the maximum count of numbers

Tags: python

For example consider the file:
input.txt

```
  12
  23
  45
  45 
  45
  34
  34
  56
  12
  12
  12
  67
  89
```

what i need is a code which will display the number repeated maximum times so the output should be as follows

```
  12   4
  45   3
  34   2
  23   1
  56   1
  67   1
  89   1
```

The code i wrote:

```
 a = []
 f = open("out","r")
 lines = f.readlines()
 for i in lines:
    j = i.split()
    a.append(j)
 print len(a)
```

it prints the total length as 13

if any one could suggest a  how to code in python to obtain the result i expect.It would be helpful??????

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> l # assume you already read the list of numbers from the file.
[12, 23, 45, 45, 45, 34, 34, 56, 12, 12, 12, 67, 89]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(l).most_common()
[(12, 4), (45, 3), (34, 2), (67, 1), (23, 1), (56, 1), (89, 1)]
```

Comment: Assumes python 2.7+. Use `collections.defaultdict` of `int` for python 2.5+.

Comment: @hughdbrown Yes, but it is okay to assume that a question about Python without any version tags will be either 2.7+ or 3+ . In this case, by looking at the OP's `print` method, I can see it is no 3+ . So I logically use the most updated version of Python 2, 2.7.5.

Comment: Not a bad interpretation. I am just saying that python is far from a single language/library these days. For example, at my company, some newly-written, 2013 python apps are in python 2.7, others in 2.6. I don't think that is unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
v={}
for line in f:      
    if v.has_key(line):
            v[line][1]+=1
    else:
            v[line]=[line,1]
for k,v in v.items():
    print v[0],v[1]
```